# Creating an index matrix depending on Reference matrix and matrix of Data matlab

Tags: matlab

given matrix A of size 6 by 6 contain  blocks of numbers,each block of size 2 by 2, and outher reference matrix R of size 2 by 12 also contain blocks of numbers, each block of size 2 by 2. the perpse of the whole process is to form a new matrix, called the Index matrix, contain index's that refer to the position of the blocks within the matrix A based on the order of the blocks within the reference matrix R. and here is an exemple

matrix A:

```
A  =[1 1 2 2 3 3; 

     1 1 2 2 3 3;

     1 1 3 3 4 4;

     1 1 3 3 4 4;

     4 4 5 5 6 6;

     4 4 5 5 6 6 ]
```

matrix R:

```
R=[1 1 2 2  3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6;

   1 1 2 2  3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 ]
```

the new matrix is:

```
Index =[1 2 3;

        1 3 4;

        4 5 6]
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my favourite three guys - [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) for an efficient and generic solution -

```
blksz = 2;                       %// blocksize
num_rowblksA = size(A,1)/blksz;  %// number of blocks along rows in A

%// Create blksz x blksz sized blocks for A and B
A1 = reshape(permute(reshape(A,blksz,num_rowblksA,[]),[1 3 2]),blksz^2,[])
R1 = reshape(R,blksz^2,1,[])

%// Find the matches with "bsxfun(@eq" and corresponding indices
[valid,idx] = max(all(bsxfun(@eq,A1,R1),1),[],3)
%// Or with PDIST2: 
%// [valid,idx] = max(pdist2(A1.',reshape(R,blksz^2,[]).')==0,[],2)
idx(~valid) = 0

%// Reshape the indices to the shapes of blocked shapes in A
Index = reshape(idx,[],num_rowblksA).'
```

Sample run with more random inputs -

```
>> A
A =
     2     1     1     2
     1     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     1     2     2     1
     1     2     1     1
>> R
R =
     2     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     1     1     1     1
     2     1     2     1     1     2     2     1     2     2     2     1
>> Index
Index =
     0     0
     5     5
     3     0
```

Comment: thank you soo much, that was soo awesome to redus a code that i write it in almost 30 lines to 7 lines. all respect!!

Comment: @SimoOs Wow! It's great to hear that! I think this one must be a lot efficient too!